# Html ActionLink won't redirect me to another controller and view

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a `HomeController` which I use to display items in a table from a text file, and each row has an `Add | Edit | Delete` action links. I have another controller called `CategoryController` which is responsible for creating and editing existing categories. The `HomeController` has an `index.cshtml` which contains those actions links. But when I click the `edit` link it has to call the Action in the `CategoryController`. But then I get the following error:

```
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
> 
> Requested URL: /Home/Edit
```

Here is my partial code for my action links (Index.cshtml):

```
 @using ToDoList
 @model ToDoList.ViewModels.CategoryItemViewModel
 //Other codes
    <td>
                            @Html.ActionLink("Add", "Create", new { id = @cats.categoryID }) |
                            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Category", new { id = @cats.categoryID }) |
                            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = @cats.categoryID })
                        </td>
```

Here is my code for the **CategoryController** `ActionResult Edit` function:

```
// GET: Category/Edit/5
        [Route("~/Category/Edit/{id}")]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {

            Category thisCategory = db.Cat.FirstOrDefault(category => category.categoryID == id);

            return View(thisCategory);
        }
```

EDIT: My `RouteConfig.cs` is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace ToDoList
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea why it does not redirect to the `CategoryController` and call the `Edit` action.

My file structure is as follows:

[image: File structure]

EDIT: My `HomeController` class is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ToDoList.Models;
using ToDoList.ViewModels;

namespace ToDoList.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        //Reading in both text files
        List<Category> categories = new List<Category>();
        List<Item> it = new List<Item>();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //CatData means CategoryData
            string CatData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/Data/Categories.txt"));
            string ItemData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/Data/Item.txt"));

            foreach (string rowInItem in ItemData.Split('\n')) {

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rowInItem)) {

                    it.Add(new Item { 

                        itemName = rowInItem.Split(',')[0],
                        itemID = Convert.ToInt32(rowInItem.Split(',')[1]),
                        categoryID = Convert.ToInt32(rowInItem.Split(',')[2]),
                        check = rowInItem.Split(',')[3]
                    });
                }
            }
            foreach (string row in CatData.Split('\n')) {

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row)) {

                    categories.Add(new Category
                    {
                        categoryName = row.Split(',')[0],
                        categoryID = Convert.ToInt32(row.Split(',')[1]),


                    }) ;
                }
            }

            var categoryItemViewControler = new CategoryItemViewModel
            {
                Cat = categories,
                It = it
            };
            return View(categoryItemViewControler);
        }


    }
}
```

EDIT: My `CategoryItemViewModel` is this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using ToDoList.Models;

namespace ToDoList.ViewModels
{
    public class CategoryItemViewModel
    {
        //For Category
        public List<Category> Cat { get; set; }
        //For Items
        public List<Item> It { get; set; }
    }
}
```

EDIT: My `Category.cs` model class is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ToDoList.Models
{
    public class Category
    {
        [Required]
        public string categoryName { get; set; }
        public int categoryID { get; set; }
        public List<Item> items { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Any help or advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `[Route("~/Category/Edit/{id}")]` seems wrong. If you want to define the route explicitly (which should not be the case since controller/action with optional Id is a default route from ASP.NET), then it should look ``[Route("Category/Edit/{id}")]``

Comment: please share your route.config , how actually you have defined route? or try this @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Category",  new { id = @cats.categoryID }, null)

Comment: With those modification, Edit should work. Add and Delete propably won't because you missed the controller name in the `@Html.ActionLink`. If you fetch the `Index.cshtml` from the `Category` controller, you don't need any controller name at all because the current controller is set as default if not specified. But from another controller, you need to specify the controller name for the two other links too.

Comment: @CharanjeetSingh Hi, I have added my `RouteConfig.cs` code. I am new to this so I'd appreciate the advice.

Comment: @Lion I haven't added anything for Add and Delete yet, as I was still testing the `Edit` one. But I shall try your way.

Comment: @Lion The thing is also that I don't have an `Index.cshtml` for the `CategoryController` because there isn't anything that I want to display before that. I am also using a textfile to read in the ID which is saved in a Category list

Comment: @Lion I have added aditional code that may be able to give some more insight.

Answer (score 0):

the Edit and the Index does not existe at the same folder, i think that you should use /category/edit as url